# Need help tapering

Tags: modeling

Im trying to make an arm for my little guy that i can animate so I want to I guess "taper" this cylinder around the other so it looks natural is there a way other than bending it a lot around the edge[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this with the Boolean Modifier. Simply add a Boolean Modifier to the small cylinder, set the Operation to **Difference**, set the Object to your large cylinder, and then apply the operation.

**However**, I would advise against using a cylinder this way on a character you are planning on animating, as a cylinder could create messy geometry. It would be better to extrude out some quads from the side of your character.

[image: From here, press E to extrude]

Comment: How would you extrude out some quads? I'm sorry I'm pretty new to Blender.

Comment: @YEET In edit mode on your large cylinder, select four faces in face select mode **Ctrl + Tab** > **Face**, and press **E** to extrude them out. I've added a picture to my answer demonstrating the selection.